# É possível emular um bilhete único com NFC do celular?

Tags: mobile

Exemplo:
Em vez de ser necessário passar o bilhete na máquina do ônibus, passar o celular!
Ou melhor.., a identificação da TAG seria a mesma em ambos dispositivos, tanto bilhete quanto celular!

Answer (score 8):

Eu diria que a melhor resposta para esta pergunta é que não é possível.

#### Porque isto não é possível?

Para entender isso você precisa primeiro saber como funciona o cartão utilizado por eles.

Não posso dizer com certeza o modelo de cartão usado pelo bilhete único, mas por informações que se encontra na internet é de que o mais provável que eles usem o smartcard *MIFARE Classic 4K*.

Simplificando o funcionamento do cartão vamos apenas dizer que este é um cartão que possui 4KB de memória que pode ter qualquer dado gravado nela, esta memória pode ser lida e gravada por um equipamento compatível, como por exemplo a máquina usada nos ônibus, nos pontos de recarga ou até mesmo os celulares com NFC.

Porém estes dados estão protegidos, por mais que um celular com NFC pode ser capaz de **ler e gravar** estes dados você não vai conseguir fazer isso com seu celular.

Você poderia tentar ler os dados com algum aplicativo como por exemplo o [NFC Mifare Classic Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touf.mfclassic&hl=pt_BR), porém como a própria descrição diz ele precisa de uma chave para poder fazer a leitura e gravação, e é esta chave que protege os dados para eles não serem lidos e alterados por qualquer um.

#### Como o cartão é usado?

Ao contrário do que pode-se pensar o cartão não possui apenas uma TAG que é usada para identificar o cartão, na verdade as informações do crédito em si estão gravadas no cartão.

Não posso dizer exatamente como foi implementado, mas ele deve ler o seu saldo diretamente no cartão, subtrair o valor da passagem e então gravar as informações de volta no cartão. Isso provavelmente também inclui a data e hora em que foi usado pela ultima vez para permitir os casos em que eles deixam você trocar de ônibus durante um certo tempo sem precisar pagar outra passagem.

Tudo isso é feito offline, eu não sei dizer se em algum momento o sistema presente no ônibus se conecta a outro sistema para sincronizar alguma informação, mas eu diria que é bem provável que isso nunca aconteça.

E não é difícil entender que o sistema deles pode realmente trabalhar offline, por mais que se possa pensar que ele deve se conectar com uma central é fácil perceber que isso nunca acontece. Se ele precisasse consultar o saldo em uma central ele precisaria de algum tipo de conexão com a mesma, por mais que você pudesse ter uma conexão 2G ou 3G, sempre vai existir áreas de sombra, onde a cobertura da rede não é boa ou até mesmo não funciona, e o tempo de resposta seria alto, os cartões geralmente respondem em instantes quando se aproximam ele do leitor.

#### Então realmente não é possível?

Talvez fosse possível se tivesse acesso a chave usada pelo cartão, pois ela seria necessária para o seu celular poder emular o funcionamento do cartão, mas na prática isso não é possível pois seria muito fácil fraudar o sistema assim.

Uma pessoa de posse desta chave pode ler e gravar cartões, então seria possível copiar todos os dados do cartão, assim talvez fosse possível criar um software que emulasse o cartão, mas seria uma cópia dos dados, que funcionaria independente do original, seria a forma mais fácil de se fraudar o sistema deles, se você simplesmente descartasse as modificações feitas durante a gravação depois de se usar o cartão você sempre teria o mesmo saldo no cartão.

Inclusive a alguns anos surgiram notícias ([tecnoblog](https://tecnoblog.net/91343/bilhete-unico-sp/),[Info](http://info.abril.com.br/noticias/seguranca/falha-permite-fraudar-bilhete-unico-de-sp-13022012-10.shl)) sobre uma possível falha de segurança nestes bilhetes, onde um hacker disse ter conseguido ler todos os dados do cartão, e por mais que ele não tenha chegado a conseguir modificar o valor do saldo por exemplo, ele disse ter conseguido fazer um backup dos dados, em seguida usou todos os créditos do cartão e por fim voltou o backup para o cartão, como resultado os créditos estavam novamente disponíveis no cartão.

Comment: Sua resposta já possui alguns anos e está muito bem elaborada, mas hoje poderia ser adicionado uma observação. Eu sei que ele perguntou foi sobre o Bilhete Único, [mas atualmente já é possível usar cartões de crédito, débito e pré-pago, celulares, smartwatches ou pulseiras com NFC](https://tecnoblog.net/318281/sao-paulo-adotar-pagamento-cartao-nfc-celular-todo-onibus-2020/) em alguns ônibus. E em breve isso será possível em todos os ônibus de São Paulo. E nestes casos posso afirmar que existe sim uma conexão com uma central através de uma rede 3G, 4G ou etc.

Answer (score 6):

Sim, é possível. Aliás, [já existem soluções implementadas.](https://tecnoblog.net/159247/app-recarga-bilhete-unico-sptrans/)

Links:

- ['SPTRANS homologa a recarga do bilhete único pelo telefone celular'](http://www.sptrans.com.br/noticias/noticia.aspx?5397), sptrans.com.br
- [aplicativo Ponto Certo Bilhete Unico](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.embryo.rpc.android), no Google Play

Comment: Pela pergunta estas soluções não são o que ele procura, já que elas permitem que você consulte o saldo do bilhete pelo celular e efetue a recarga do mesmo, o que ele quer me parece ser uma forma de usar o celular no lugar do bilhete no ônibus.

Comment: Seu comentário é válido, @LeandroGodoyRosa, mas acho que a dúvida dele era um pouco mais básica. No meu entendimento: "A implementação presente nos dispositivos móveis atuais suporta a emulação do mesmo comportamento apresentado pelas tags NFC utilizadas no serviço de Bilhete Único?"

Comment: pelo que entendi as soluções postadas por você faz com que o celular funcione de forma parecida com o leitor de cartão presente no ônibus, então realmente pode-se dizer que ele pode simular este mesmo comportamento, porém o contrário não é válido, fazer o celular se identificar como se fosse o cartão, que ao meu entender é isso que ele quer, simplesmente encostar o celular na máquina do ônibus e ela ler ele como se estivesse lendo o cartão. Vou formular uma resposta explicando o porque isso não é possível visto que isso tem a ver com o como o cartão funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Ola. 
Após longas noites de estudo sobre a tecnologia, acredito que seja possível sim a cópia do cartão!
Não é possível através do celular, mas sim através de um aparelho de leitura e gravação da mesma frequência da Mifare.
A ideia é capturar todos os dados do cartão original, salvar como arquivo. Então, gravar os dados copiados em um segundo cartão com a mesma capacidade. Quando acabar os créditos é só resetar o cartão gravado através da imagem de dados anterior...

Acredito que a captura dos dados no campo magnético através da cópia completa, "sem precisar de nenhuma criptografia" é possível sim.

Comment: Não acredito que seja possível pois o cartão requer uma chave para a leitura dos dados, do jeito que você fala parece que ele funciona simplesmente como um dispositivo de armazenamento de dados, mas na verdade ele está mais para um hardware que você solicita os dados passando uma senha e se a senha estiver correta ele retorna os dados